# JQuery UI tabs header too big with css floated two-column layout

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-float, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to set up JQuery UI tabs in the right column of a two-column layout powered by `float: left`.

The problem is: the **header** of the tabs gets sized to have the **same height** as the left column.

HTML:

```
<div id="zone_content">
    <div id="zone_main">
        <div id="zone_left">
            <p>Stuff</p><p>Stuff</p><p>Stuff</p><p>Stuff</p><p>Stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div id="zone_tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Another Tab</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>blah blah blah blah</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>bloh bloh bloh bloh</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#zone_tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#zone_main {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#zone_left {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}
#zone_tabs {
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/576pc/).

I noticed it might be the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802358/jquery-ui-tabs-having-problems-with-css-float), but while the answer of adding `float: left;` on the #zone_tabs corrects the header height, it also push the tabs down to after the end of the left column. (It does so when the left column is large enough: 250px in the jsfiddle ; if one reduce it to 100px in both places where it's specified, the tabs find their intended place.)

So, could anyone help me, and explain me why all of this happen ?

*Versions*: Chrome 23 or Firefox 23, JQuery 1.8.2, JQuery UI 1.9.1

Comment: Just remove margin left from #zone_tabs and add float left. Of course, if your container, #zone_main, width is less than 250px (#zone_left width) + #zone_tabs width, it will push the tabs under the left column.

Comment: @MihaiAlex: it works like you say, but in my actual case the width of #zone_left is 500px and it breaks again (tabs pushed under #zone_left), as visible by toying with the jsfiddle. The #zone_main has a width of 100%, not specified.

Comment: ...and the text in the tabs is longer than in the example, which also causes the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/sbZ6C/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same goal by using `display:inline-block;` and setting percentage widths.  However, now that I've edited my answer, its of note that using float negates the need to set display:inline-block, but I'm leaving the code just so both ways can be viewed.

[SEE THIS JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbZ6C/3/)

Basically, the only thing you need to watch out for in this scenario is making sure that any padding or margins inside the two divs(zone_left and zone_tabs) are also set to percentage so the view adjusts in different screen sizes.

```
#zone_main {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#zone_left {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
}
#zone_tabs {
    display:inline-block;
    width:65%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case the top border of the tabs area goes up and down depending on the amount of text inside each tab (as seen in the jsfiddle). (And why aren't fixed width allowed ?)

Comment: @manur ah ok.  See my new fiddle.  I've combined the other questions solution with mine to demonstrate a valid answer.  I'm basically using percent in this example to make sure that both elements will fit inside the container(ie (30% + 65%) < 100%).  You can used fixed width but both elements will need to have the fix width defined to be sure that the float in the same row.  In you fiddle in the question comments you only have zone left width defined so zone tabs  defaults to a width of 100% since its not explicitly defined.